# jQuery delete class elements except with a certain ID

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, hide

I need to `hide()` all class level elements of `'.dd-container'` except when that element has an `id` of `'#tools'`.

I tried the following (which didn't work) but I'm pretty sure I fudged the syntax:

```
$('div:has(.dd-container):not(#tools .dd-container)').hide();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$("div:not(#tools)").find(".dd-container").hide();
```

**edit:** Think I mis-read the question. Is there one `dd-container`-class that also has an `id` of tools? If so, then you need to change it to this:

```
$("div").find(".dd-container:not(#tools)").hide();
```

or this: (Which should perform faster according to some tests I did a while back)

```
$(".dd-container:not(#tools)", "div").hide();
```

The reason it's faster, is because it's looking for the classes first, instead of looking for all divs, and then going through them all...I think.

Comment: Yeah perhaps I didn't explain it too well. The first one didn't work because, as you said, the dd-container has an id of tools. I ended up solving this before I seen your last edit, but I solved it exactly the same way.
Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div:has(.dd-container):not(#tools.dd-container)').hide();
```

(Note the lack of space after '#tools')
or

```
$('div:has(.dd-container):not(#tools)').hide();
```

(As ids are unique, you can probably dispense with the class specifier for the 'not' selector)

Answer (score 0):

```
#tools .dd-container
```

there is a blank between #tools and .dd-container
that means all children of #tools with the class .dd-container 
e.g.

```
<table id="tools"><tr class='dd-container'>
```

so #tools.dd-container should work however the answer of peirix is much easier to read.